# Please input a file for upload error in joomla

Tags: upload, joomla

I have recently moved my joomla site from my test server to live server.

In backend, when i try to upload image in media manager, there is an error saying Please input a file for upload. The max file size to upload is 10MB and m trying uploading small images. But still i got this error.

Can anyone help me with this. Any help is highly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: please tell us also your server OS?

Comment: What about the browser? Is it the same in all browsers?

Comment: yes its same in all browser and also in every terminal .

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser, check the directory permissions (help menu), check your java version.

Comment: its not working in any browser and any other terminal . The folder stories have write permission but also in that folder the image is not uploaded. It again says (with warning icon) Please input a file to upload. i was fine working in test server but not working when moved to live server.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just check the stories folder permissions. Joomla uploads files to the temp directory then moves them to the final location. Make sure all your permissions are set properly - 755 for folders, 644 for files. Also make sure that your temp directories are set correctly. If you just moved the site, you likely will need to update those for the file structure of the server.

Comment: I checked all the permission . But it didnt work. Still i get the error Please input a file for upload. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Did you confirm that the temp directory paths are correct? Are you using the Flash uploader? If you are using the Flash uploader you probably need to turn that off and use the PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the media setting in Global Configuration.

And check the path to temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Too many times put "Check permission"

That's it's wrong information. Not all server run with obsolete mod_php. Too many run on mode CGI, Fast-CGI, with SuXEC.

In this case, permission ok are 600, 700 to 644 - 755

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have a discrepancy between the URL of your site and the one set in your configuration.php. They should match.

```
var $live_site = 'http://www.yourwebsiste.com.br';
```

Thanks to http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2096980 for pointing me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

check that file_uploads setiing is enabled on the server in php.ini, I had the sam problem and this was the solution